# Datatable Select query Date range issue

Tags: c#

I have a datatable in which I am selecting value by date range using a select query but it returns 0 count. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
string sUserName = "joe";
string Value = "4";
string sProcessStart = "2015-08-28 12:12:26 PM";
string sProcessEnd = "2015-08-28 12:29:26 PM";

DataTable dtDLCD = new DataTable();

DataColumn dtcolumn = new DataColumn("UserName");
dtcolumn.DefaultValue = "joe";
dtDLCD.Columns.Add(dtcolumn);

DataColumn dtcolumn1 = new DataColumn("Value");
dtcolumn1.DefaultValue = "4";
dtDLCD.Columns.Add(dtcolumn1);

DataColumn dtcolumn3 = new DataColumn("StartDate");
dtcolumn3.DefaultValue = "2015-08-28 12:20:26 PM";
dtDLCD.Columns.Add(dtcolumn3);

DataColumn dtcolumn4 = new DataColumn("EndDate");
dtcolumn4.DefaultValue = "2015-08-28 12:29:26 PM";
dtDLCD.Columns.Add(dtcolumn4);

DataRow drow = dtDLCD.NewRow();
dtDLCD.Rows.Add(drow);


DataRow[] drDocDetails = dtDLCD.Select("UserName = '" + sUserName +
                                   "' AND Value = '" + Value +
                                   "' AND StartDate >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(sProcessStart).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt") +
                                   "' AND EndDate <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(sProcessEnd).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt") + "'");

int count = drDocDetails.Count();
```

Comment: reformatted the code block

Comment: Are you sure you don't have code not shown here that is modifying the count variable? It works fine for me when I run it.

Comment: Don't forget to declare the column type: `dtcolumn3.DataType = typeof(DateTime);`

Comment: As @mjw said, the code as shown works. https://dotnetfiddle.net/70ey3g

Answer (score -1):

What you have done in this code example is to define the table itself: you have not added any data rows. (In a database table, "field" and "column" are pretty much synonymous.)

At the end of the code segment you create an instance of a row object--but you do not define any values for each column. You call the Add() method--but there's nothing in the row to add.

Add data (one row per record) then your record count will be non-zero.

Comment: Nope, running the provide code over here produces a count of 1 for me.

Comment: How? He adds a blank row to the data table: the values of StartDate and EndDate are NULL. Null propagation means that the WHERE clause evaluates to NULL, so the query returns no records.

Rather than debate the OP's homework question (welcome back to campus, kid!) let's agree that his problem is that he hasn't put any data in the table....

Comment: Don't take my word for it. Run the code yourself, count = 1.